# Getting all documents from MongoDB with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

For some reason I'm having a problem getting all documents from MongoDB using mongoose. I want to retrieve all documents and place them into an array for later processing, but this seems to be impossible. Here is the code I'm using:

```
module.exports = { 
    create: (req, res, next) => {
        // console.log(req.body);
        let userClaim = new UserClaim(getUserParams(req.body));
        let userArr = [];
        UserClaims.find({}).then((users) => {
            users.forEach(user => {
                userArr.push(user);
        });
```

If I print each user inside the `forEach` statement, it works. However the array is always empty at the end of the operation. I've stepped through the code with a debugger as well. The array will populate, but return to being empty as soon as the `forEach` method completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following solution,

```
module.exports = { 
    create: async (req, res, next) => {
        let userClaim = new UserClaim(getUserParams(req.body));
        const userArr = await UserClaims.find({}).lean()
// Print and check userArr
      }
```

Comment: So I guess it was a weird async issue.